# Architecture for uploading Images to Azure Blob Storage without Mobile Services

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I´m planning a Azure Web Api and one of the requests is to let users upload Images from their mobile devices to our Blob Storage. The Clients are Windows Phones, iPhones and Android Phones.

Trying to plan the solution, I found a lot of tutorials doing this with Azure Mobile Services. But with scaling requirements, this solution should not be used. Instead we want the Clients to upload Images directly into our Blob Storage, secured by `SAS` (generated by our Api).

Does anyone knows how to handle the upload of all kinds of actual mobile OS **without Mobile Services**? Does anyone have some links to tutorials, how-to´s, etc.?

Edit:

I´m not shure, how all different devices handle their photo Uploads?

Posting form data? Mulitpart?
Uploading via REST?
Uploading via FTP?

Because of this question I search for some hints to plan the project forward to accept the simplest solution for all mobile OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any application capable of sending web requests could do the trick, you'll have to be more specific about your needs.

Using the blob REST API ("put" method) [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179451.aspx) is doable from any application. It's only a matter of sending a Http request containing the right headers and the blob as request body. You'll probably have to come up with a way for distributing the shared acces keys if the containers aren't public.